# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. I am trying to deploy aws lambda using serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy AWS lambda using Serverless framework from visual studio code and
I am getting this error.
"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method."

Answer (score 0):

This is an error from AWS themselves. It is likely that the clock on your local machine is not set to the correct time therefore the signature process fails.